# What's the cleanest way to organize if/else blocks for assigning a variable from multiple potential datasources?

Tags: java, variable-assignment, code-cleanup

What's the cleanest way to sequentially attempt to assign a variable from a dataset, moving to the following if the former returns `null` or is empty? I'm working in Java.

Pseudo code:

I know `.contains` exists for maps; the real code I'm working with isn't a map, but this should give a decent illustration.

```
Object variable = firstmap.get(key);
if (variable == null) {
  variable = secondmap.get(key);
  if (variable == null) {
    variable = thirdmap.get(key);
    if (variable == null) {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

I could break this up like this, sure, but it still doesn't seem great:

```
Object variable = firstmap.get(key);
if (variable == null) {
  variable = secondmap.get(key);
}
if (variable == null) {
  variable = thirdmap.get(key);
}
if (variable == null) {
  ...
}
...
```

Is there a cleaner way? Having a true brain burp.

Comment: This is opinion based. What seems "great" to you?

Comment: `Optional.ofNullable(x).or(() -> y).or(() -> z)...`

Comment: @khelwood with the gold medal here, that's exactly the thing my mind was hunting for.

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing is known as a "coalesce".  You could try something like this:

```
public <T> T coalesce(T ... values) {
    for (T value : values) {
      if (value != null) {
         return value;
      }
    return null;
}
```

And set the variable with

```
variable = coalesce(firstMap.get(key), secondMap.get(key), thirdMap.get(key));
```

Comment: This is a super cool way to achieve this, thanks!

Comment: I don't think this is very elegant, since this way you will need to search through all of the maps even if the first one contains the key.

Comment: This will trigger the computation of all `values` parameter, which would be cost ineffective.  Should use a `Supplier` instead.

Comment: Sure, using a `Supplier` would be better, I was really just looking for anything to jog my memory since I've been staring at the same block from a legacy source for days now

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
Object variable;
boolean found =
    (variable = firstmap.get(key)) != null ||
    (variable = secondmap.get(key)) != null ||
    (variable = thirdmap.get(key)) != null ||
    ...
    (variable = nthmap.get(key)) != null;
```

It will only check the maps until it gets to the first one that contained the key because || is short circuiting.

Comment: This could be another one to keep in mind. Thanks